# Modal Dialog Box not showing in ASP.NET web

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am currently trying to use Modal Dialog box from Bootstrap. I have did exactly what the tutorial shows but whenever I click on my button, the Modal Dialog does not show. May I know why?

Here's my code

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server"  ImageUrl="image.url" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login" />

            <div class="modal" id="login" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <label>Login</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>EmAIL-iD</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email-Id" id="email" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button value="Login" id="login"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap depends on jQuery already being loaded so it should be imported before the bootstrap.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

If that is your issue you'll be seeing a `jQuery is not defined` error in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You are using server side control(asp:ImageButton). SO postback will happen.

Use button control

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: Is there no way I can keep ImageButton? Because I need an image to act as a button

Comment: Create a css class with image as background, and add this class to button.    <style>
   .bgButton{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 2px solid #AD235E;
   border-radius: 100px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px; background-image: url(images/Sun.jpg);
   }
   </style>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg bgButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Open Modal

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for this.

First, you have nested forms. Change the outer one to a div:

```
<div runat="server">
```

Secondly, there are 2 elements with the id login:

```
<div class="modal" id="login" tabindex="-1">
<button value="Login" id="login"></button>
```

Change the id of the button to something different.

If it still fails after these corrections, open up developer tools in your browser (F12) and see if there are errors in the console (maybe the jquery lib could not be reached).

Comment: If I change the outer one to a div, they will prompt an error stating that `Control 'ctl01' of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class with image as background, and add this class to button.

```
                <style>
                .bgButton{
                font-size: 18px;
                border: 2px solid #AD235E;
                border-radius: 100px;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px; background-image: url(images/Sun.jpg);
                }
                </style>  
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg bgButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"></button>
```